# Rails: how to send a string from controller to view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to rails and I want my controller to update label/html field in view with the variable @msg created from an action. right now I have,

View form:

```
<%= form_tag({controller: "home", action: "drawMoney"}) do %>
<h1> Draw Out </h1>
    <%= number_field_tag :draw, min: 1, max:1000 %>
    <%= date_field_tag :customDate %>
<%= submit_tag "Save" %>
<% end %>

<p>
  <%= "#{@msg}" %>
</p>
```

Controller

```
def drawMoney
@drawAmount = params[:draw]
@credit = Credit.getCredit('1')
@updateAmount = updatePrincipal(@credit.principal, @drawAmount)
@newLimit = updateLimit(@credit.currLimit, @drawAmount)

@msg = "success!"

if (@transaction = Transaction.create(userId: @credit.userId, date: params[:customDate], OPB: @credit.principal, amount: @drawAmount).valid?)
  @credit.update(principal: @updateAmount, currLimit: @newLimit)
  @transaction = Transaction.create(userId: @credit.userId, date: params[:customDate], OPB: @credit.principal, amount: @drawAmount)
else
  @msg = "not valid"
end

redirect_to action: "index"
end
```

I've read ruby docs and youtube tutorial, tried putting @msg in the view instead and @msg in html etc.. but this is not printing anything to the view, and couldn't really find answers from search. Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT:

I tried changing to <%= @msg %> but it doesn't work..
so the method is called when I click the submit button, and until then there is no @msg instance. Could that be a problem?

Comment: It's because you're redirecting.  It loses all of your set variables.  Use the flash as @imechemi suggests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you redirect to index, your currently defined variables will be cleared.

controller

```
flash[:msg] = "Success"
redirect_to action: "index"
```

view

```
<% if flash[:msg] %>
  <div class="message"><%= flash[:msg] %></div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<pre>
  <%= @msg %>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this `<%= "#{@msg}" %>` to `<%= @msg %>`You don't have to interpolate here, rails view have direct access to controller instances when you create it with a @ sign.

Comment: Thanks for the input! :)

Comment: @imechemi is correct, important point. when you redirect to index, variables in index is now accessible in the view.